# The local variable may not have been initialized

Tags: java, android, timepicker

ISSUE:

I have a TimePicker which I'd like to use to save the value of the long/string "minutes" which represents the total number of minutes between the current time and the time selected by the timepicker.

For example: If it is currently 7:30 and the user selects 8:30 it will save 60 minutes as the value of minutes.

I've managed to implement the following source code (shown below) however I'm getting a few errors stating:

```
"The local variable tp may not have been initialized"
```

Using the method suggested in the comments below - although I'm following the instructions precisely.

COMPILER PROBLEMS:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The local variable tp may not have been initialized AddEditDevice.java      line 119    Java Problem
The local variable tp may not have been initialized AddEditDevice.java      line 120    Java Problem
```

SOURCE:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AddEditDevice extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;
     private TextView ssidTextView;
     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     TimePicker tp;


      // @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);
          WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
          String ssidString = info.getSSID();

          if (ssidString.startsWith("\"") && ssidString.endsWith("\"")){
              ssidString = ssidString.substring(1, ssidString.length()-1);
 }

          //TextView ssidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
          ssidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
          ssidTextView.setText(ssidString); 

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);






          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));    
             String time = extras.getString("time");
             String[] parts = time.split(":");
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]));
             timeEt.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
             timeEt.setIs24HourView(false);


          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditDevice.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });}


       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           TimePicker tp;
           cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
           cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.getCurrentMinute());
           long minutes = (cal.getTimeInMillis() -
               Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) / 1000 / 60;
       }



           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
//                Log.i("Test for Null", ""+dbConnector+" "+nameEt+" "+capEt+" "+timeEt+" "+codeEt+" "+ssidTextView);
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                              + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString(),
                       ssidTextView.getText().toString());

              }
              else
              {
                 dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                         nameEt.getText().toString(),
                            capEt.getText().toString(),
                              timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                                  + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                              codeEt.getText().toString(),
                              ssidTextView.getText().toString());
              }
           }
}
```

Comment: You're using an uninitialized value in your main method **(TimePicker tp;
           cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());)**. However: your initial question was asked and answered. And you're not helping yourself by eternalizing your original question. You should have marked it as answered and continued your development. Afterwards you should have asked follow-up questions as new questions, not as an ever-evolving eternal question.

Comment: Been there. Done that. No need to thank me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `java.util.Calendar` to get current values and subtract.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimePicker tp;

// ...

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.getCurrentMinute());
long minutes = (cal.getTimeInMillis() -
    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) / 1000 / 60;
```

**Edit**: Try this Java console application. A proof that it works.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 58);

        long minutes = (cal.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) / 1000 / 60;

        System.out.println(minutes);
    }

}
```

Returns `4` at `20:54` of my local time.

Comment: Yes, but there's no need to keep Date object as a member, you can use it locally. Also I've edited my answer, to deal with some midnight issues. You should update your code, so it matches. (This midnight issue occurs when user starts to pick time at 23:59 and finishes at 0:01).

Comment: Wait a moment. That's correct, but... you don't save the `minutes` anywhere. Actually, you're discarding it with first `}`... :-)

Comment: Awesome - thanks! I edited my source above... but now Im getting an error stating:

Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int AddEditDevice.java

Comment: I think I just needed to use a long value instead of an int : )

Comment: I updated my source above - moved the } etc - everything look good to you? : )

Comment: You're totally right with the `long`, sorry! You calculate `minutes` properly, but you never use it againg. How is it supposed to jump into your database? :)

Comment: Make `long minutes` a member variable and use it in `saveContact()` (instead of  `timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":" + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString()` use `"" + minutes` or `Long.toString(minutes)`.

Comment: I updated my source above [thanks for your help with this!] see anything else I might have missed?

Comment: Looks OK, except for code formatting issues and `newCon.put("minutes", ssid);` fragment. You probably meant `minutes` instead of `ssid`. But just check it, that's the best way to verify code.

Comment: Done! BTW - all of a sudden after adding that... I can't view anything in my database - any suggestions? (I updated my source code above - im 100% sure it has to do with the changes we just made - it was working less than 5 minutes ago and I havent changed anything else)

Comment: I think we broke it...

: ( 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146105/cannot-view-any-items-from-sqlite-database

Comment: I fixed it... but I'm getting a zero value when I use your method - mind if I post my source?

Comment: Do post it. I've updated my answer with sample code that does work. Doubtlessly you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Updated - we've made quite a few changes trying to get it to work - still no luck as of yet... (I've got a couple brains working on this - but if you know the answer: please let us know!)

Comment: That's right. I've forgotten about that. `java.util.Date` is obsolete. Use `java.util.Calendar` instead. I've just updated the answer.

Comment: Can you show me how I can use it in my current implementation?

Comment: I need to use this to find the difference between the current time and a time value set by my timepicker - Im just not sure how...

Comment: Instantiate a `Calendar` object instead of a `Date` one. And in place when you compute `minutes`, place my updated code for this computation.

Moreover, you're probably getting 0 minutes, because of where in the program flow you're computing the difference. You've put `long minutes = ((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / (1000 * 60);` in class body. It will be computed as soon as this class is instantiated. *Not* when user selects a time.

Comment: I've implemented your suggestion @Michal Rus 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           TimePicker tp;
           cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, tp.getCurrentHour());
           cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tp.getCurrentMinute());
           long minutes = (cal.getTimeInMillis() -
               Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()) / 1000 / 60;
       }

But I'm getting two errors stating "The local variable tp may not have been initialized" although it seems to be declared right there in the source you provided

Comment: You must be kidding. If all that's true, then programming is not your thing, sorry.

Comment: We weren't using your solution... it turns out the method he was using was depreciated so it was a futile effort (I was just following along with his guidance - I should have realized what the issue was earlier)

Comment: Any suggestions regarding the error im getting when implementing your suggested method? Im not sure if I should use something such as TimePicker tp = null; or not... any suggestions? Your suggestion did not include a local variable for the value tp