# TimePicker Saves Zero Value in SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a TimePicker which I'd like to use to determine a length of time a user can stay connected. Lets say the time now is 10:00 if the user selects 11:00 - I'd like the source code below to determine that there are 60 minutes between the current time - and the time selected and set that to a string/long (minutes) which I then have displayed as a textview.

I've coded everything as I thought it should be - however the textview never seems to update with minutes value. Everytime I attempt to view the data - I get a value of 0 not matter what the timepicker is set to.

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm stumped at the moment and I'm not sure what else to try.

ADDEDITDEVICE.JAVA (where the timepicker and minutes determination takes place)

```
public class AddEditDevice extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;
     private TextView ssidTextView;
     Date date = new Date();
     TimePicker tp;




      // @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          setContentView(R.layout.add_country);
          WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
          String ssidString = info.getSSID();

          if (ssidString.startsWith("\"") && ssidString.endsWith("\"")){
              ssidString = ssidString.substring(1, ssidString.length()-1);


          //TextView ssidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
          ssidTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
          ssidTextView.setText(ssidString); 

          nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
          capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
          codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
          timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);






          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

          if (extras != null)
          {
             rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
             nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
             capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
             codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));    
             String time = extras.getString("time");
             String[] parts = time.split(":");
             timeEt.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]));
             timeEt.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
             timeEt.setIs24HourView(false);

             date.setMinutes(tp.getCurrentMinute());
             date.setHours(tp.getCurrentHour());
             Long.toString(minutes);


          }

          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditDevice.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });}
       }

       long minutes = ((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / (1000 * 60);


           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
//                Log.i("Test for Null", ""+dbConnector+" "+nameEt+" "+capEt+" "+timeEt+" "+codeEt+" "+ssidTextView);
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                              + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString(),   
                          Long.toString(minutes),
                       ssidTextView.getText().toString());

              }
              else
              {
                 dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                         nameEt.getText().toString(),
                            capEt.getText().toString(),
                              timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                                  + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                              codeEt.getText().toString(),
                              Long.toString(minutes),
                              ssidTextView.getText().toString());
              }
           }
}
```

VIEW COUNTRY.JAVA (where the minutes data set by the timepicker should be visible)

```
public class ViewCountry extends NfcBeamWriterActivity {

    private static final String TAG = ViewCountry.class.getName();

    protected Message message;

    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    private static final int MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
    private long rowID;
    private TextView nameTv;
    private TextView capTv;
    private TextView codeTv;
    private TextView timeTv;
    private TextView ssidTv;
    private TextView combined;
    private TextView minutes;
    //String timetest = "300";


    // String a="\"";
    // String b="\"";

    // String message1 = a + ssidTv.getText().toString() +"," +
    // capTv.getText().toString()+b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_country);


    SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("name", true);
        editor.putBoolean("cap", true);
        editor.putBoolean("code", true);
        editor.putBoolean("time", true);
        editor.putBoolean("ssid",true);
        editor.putBoolean("minutes",true);
        editor.putBoolean("timetest",true);
        editor.commit();



        setDetecting(true);
        startPushing();

        setUpViews();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID);
    }

    private void setUpViews() {
        nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
        timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
        codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
        ssidTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifiSSID);
        minutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Minutes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
    }

    private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> {
        DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params) {
            dbConnector.open();
            return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            result.moveToFirst();
            int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
            int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
            int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
            int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");
            int ssidIndex = result.getColumnIndex("ssid");

            nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
            capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
            timeTv.setText(result.getString(timeIndex));
            codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));
            ssidTv.setText(result.getString(ssidIndex));

            result.close();
            dbConnector.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.editItem:
            Intent addEditContact = new Intent(this, AddEditDevice.class);

            // addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
            // addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
            // addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
            // addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact);
            return true;

        case R.id.user1SettingsSave:
            Intent Tap = new Intent(this, Tap.class);
            startActivity(Tap);
            return true;

        case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void deleteContact() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

        alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle);
        alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);

        alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
                        final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(
                                ViewCountry.this);

                        AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask = new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Object doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]);
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        };

                        deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });
                    }
                });

        alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),  
capEt.getText().toString(),  
timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":" + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),  
codeEt.getText().toString(),  
minutes,  
Long.toString(minutes),  
ssidTextView.getText().toString());
```

You have that code to add a contact, BUT in your database conector you have:

```
public void insertContact(String name,
String cap,
String code, 
String time, 
long minutes, 
String ssid,
String string){
```

I think that don't match, so this is why don't insert correctly.
BTW i can't comment at the moment because i need 50 reputation.

Regards

Comment: I updated my source code above to match - still cant view anything I save to my database using CountryList

Comment: Why on "onPostExecute(Cursor result){} You have: ALTER TABLE my_table;       ADD COLUMN new_column;

Comment: It was a suggestion from another user - I've removed it and updated my source code above - it cleared up the "problems" I got after implementing their suggestion - I currently have zero problems - other than the fact I can't save/retrieve data after adding that minutes value (the source code above is exactly how I have it now)

Comment: I posted my original working source code above - not sure if that helps anyone - I have no idea what I did to break this... but I really need to figure out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Oh i understand know. You need delete your table first (if you don't need data, make a backup if you need), and then run your code again!

Comment: I was able to view the data by doing so - but now it's showing a zero value for some strange reason (I updated my notes and source code above)

Comment: I guess is best create a new question here in stackoverflow. The first question is answered so you close that question. And open other with a diferent question. That way other users can see the problem/answer to the first question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28668/discussion-between-miguel-maciel-and-bill-florentine)

Answer (score -1):

USE CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T/N then your problem wil be solved.

otherwise it will override the current table at the same time all the data will be lost.

Comment: If you're looking for where I save data to my database it's AddEditCountry.java (I added a summary of each class file above)

Comment: @coding devil Not an answer. This can be a comment.

Comment: @BillFlorentine i think it's the problem abut ur onCreate() method in your DB class like Create Table IF NOT Exists TN check this statement exists or not otherwise if you are writing like this CREATE TABLE TN it will override the entire table and previous data will be lost. so please check it.